# Link dhtmlx gantt chart to a specific logged in user

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

So I am working on a progress tracking web application using asp.net MVC. So I need to have each user create a Gantt chart and its saved in the database. I am using the DHTMLX Gantt chart library.
my question is how can I get each user to have a different Gantt chart saved for them, just need help with the logic behind that or a query to get to save a particular gantt chart for a specific user.
I am using Visual Studio, ASP.NET MVC, and SQL Server database.
Thank you

myquery to return the gantt chart for specific user:

```
public ActionResult ViewPlan()
    {
        using (var db = new ProgressTrackerEntities())
        {
            Milestone data = new Milestone();
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var result = from rowM in db.Milestones
                         join userrow in db.Students on rowM.StudentNumber equals userrow.StudentNumber
                         where userrow.StudentNumber == userId
                         select rowM;
            //return chart for that user not sure how to return chart

        }

        return View();
    }
```

the javascript code for the chart:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<link href="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        // specifying the date format
        gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
        // initializing gantt
        gantt.init("gantt_here");

        // initiating data loading
        gantt.load("/api/data");
        // initializing dataProcessor
        var dp = new gantt.dataProcessor("/api/");
        // and attaching it to gantt
        dp.init(gantt);
        // setting the REST mode for dataProcessor
        dp.setTransactionMode("REST");
    });
</script> </head>   <div id="gantt_here" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>
</body> </html>
```

[relationship between student and the milestone table which saves the gantt chart details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZJqp.png)

what the gantt chart looks like:
[gantt chart created by any user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzlp2.png)

Comment: You should add a minimal code example explaining what you want.

Comment: i updated the question with some code let me know what other code you may need